# Button Click without any ID C# Webbrowser

Tags: c#, button

How to click the button without any ID? 
I tried it with the web browser in C#. 
I tried the following code:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");  
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)  
{  
   if (el.GetAttribute("class").Equals("bb987"))
{  
el.InvokeMember("click");  
}  
}
```

This is the web code:

```
<span class="fr66n">
<button class="front"><span class="bb987" aria-label="Press">
</span></button></span>
```

Anybody who can help?

Comment: "I tried the following code" - and that solved your problem? If not, what isn't working and what is expected? Also, buttons don't have that class value.

Comment: There is no error message. The button is not clicked. Any idea why they don't find this button?

Comment: The code gets `button`s, loops through each of them, and asks if the button has a `class` with value `"bb987"`. There's not a single button with that class. The button has class `"front"`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will test it with el.GetAttribute("class").Equals("front").

Comment: I tested the code. No button clicked.... Any ideas? I have no error messages.
Is there a diverent way?